# unknown error trying to fs.readfilesync files with more than 120MB

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, file, fs

An error is throwed when i try to get content using fs.readFileSync() from a .xlsx with more than 120MB.

When i do:

`fs.readFileSync("Z:\pasta1\200Maq.xlsx')`

the response is:

```
Uncaught Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, read
```

look:

[image: image with the code and the 'UNKNOWN: unknow error, read']

What is the problem? How can i make it work?

Comment: try with file stream instead of readFilesync

Comment: So the problem is the memory, right?